# CI pagination syntax for getting results

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Assume that the config is done and it is intialized, then time for the results to be paginated.

On this line of code.

```
$data['records'] = $this->db->get('tablename', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
```

Is there anyway of changing the above line of code. Since I have 3 tables with ERD relationship. So in my 3rd table consists lots of rows that are connected to the other 2 tables. I want to make a model function where i will manually query the results. How am i supposed to write it?

```
$data['records'] = $this->load->model('manual_querying'), $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Im not sure if its correct, i am still unable to test it if its correct since im not done with my pagination yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model, write a function

```
public function get_records($per_page,$page)
{
   $this->db->select("*");
   $this->db->from("table1 as t1");
   $this->db->join("table2 as t2","t1.id = t2.t1_id");
   $this->db->join("table3 as t3","t1.id = t3.t1_id");
   $this->db->limit($per_page,$page);
   $res = $this->db->get();
   return $res; 
}
```

In controller,

```
$this->load->model('your_model');
$data['records'] = $this->your_model->get_records($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
```

Comment: What is $condition = array(); line for?

Comment: You can pass some where condition. But i didn't write code to add condition. So just remove it.